# Java Binary Search Tree _ the distance from root to nearest leaf

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I like to know the base algorithm to calculate the closest leaf distance from root
in Binary Search tree

I want to use code like this,

```
public int closeness() {
    return closeness(root);
}

public int closeness(Node x) {

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your tree balanced?

Comment: no need to be balanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the minimum of the "closeness" of each branch plus one:

```
public int closeness(Node x) {
  if (x == null) {
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
  if (x.left == null && x.right == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.min(closeness(x.left), closeness(x.right)) + 1;
}
```

Or, slightly more verbose without the "MAX_VALUE" trick to ignore empty branches in Math.min()

```
public int closeness(Node x) {
  if (x.left == null) {
    if (x.right == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    return closedness(x.right) + 1;
  }
  if (x.right == null) {
    return closedness(x.left) + 1;
  }
  return Math.min(closeness(x.left), closeness(x.right)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Perhaps clarify / expand the question?

Comment: emmm okay leaf node don't have any child but the if statement return when it doesn't have one child. However when I change it to && it make null pointer exception error...

Comment: Ah, sorry, had wrongfully seen null as a leaf node, should be fixed now.

Comment: oh Thank you keep helping me out :) Can you explain " return Integer.MAX_VALUE; " this part little bit?

Comment: This is just to avoid checking x.left and x.right for null separately, making sure null branches are ignored via Math.min() when calculating the child closedness

Comment: What kind of error? If it's just always off by one, perhaps you need to return 1 for the leaf node instead of 0? Otherwise, perhaps provide an example of the tree and expected result?

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea for implementing your requirement would be to recursively traverse your BST (left and right sub-trees) and along the way, calculate the number of nodes that you had to pass through before reaching a leaf node. Finally, you can use a simple MIN/MAX function to determine the closest leaf node from the root. Note that the idea works for calculating the distance and not the actual (closest) leaf node itself. Implementing that should not be too difficult, I assume. Feel free to ask should you have any further questions.